# INSERT INTO... VALUES with inexisting values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a question about insert data in a table.
My table is just composed of a primary key (that is composed by two foreign key).
The problem is: I don't know how to execute my script to insert all rows except non-existing values. Because in the script, some of the inserts are not available anymore.

For some reason, someone gave me the insert script but with some foreign key that were delete. So when I executed the script, I get an error "Constraint fail..." and it's normal.
But how to insert rows easily to avoid error due to invalid foreign key?

```
INSERT INTO `X_Y` (`x_id`, `y_id`) VALUES
(4, 1),
(4, 2),
(4, 3),
(4, 4),
(4, 5),
(5, 6),
(5, 7),
(5, 8),
(6, 9),
(6, 10),
(7, 11),
(8, 12),
(8, 13),
(11, 18),
(12, 19),
... ( about 2000 insert)
(1680, 2071);
```

For example : insert (4,1) can't be executed because foreign key x_id 4 does not exist anymore.

Comment: @trincot : not sure this is what OP wants, the problem is not about duplicate entry but insert on key that doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Not exactly the same problem but it seem that INSERT INTO IGNORE... solve my problem, so thank you very much. Don't thought that it was so simple :)

Comment: @MickaelLeger, the problem really has the same solution: it does not matter what the constraint violation is about (foreign key constraint or unique constraint), if the solution is about ignoring errors and continue the execution.

Comment: @trincot : sure, but INSERT IGNORE will INSERT value that shouldn't be there, no? I'm still curious for an answer that allow to check if foreign key exists before insert

Comment: @MickaelLeger It seems that INSERT IGNORE don't insert "dead" data, all data with "error" are not in my table anymore. For example, all insert with foreign key "4" are not insert in my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first inserting your data into a temporary table, with no constraints:

```
INSERT INTO temp (x_id, y_id)
VALUES
    (4, 1),
    (4, 2),
    ...;
```

Then, use the following query to insert into your target table:

```
INSERT INTO X_Y (x_id, y_id)
SELECT x_id, y_id
FROM temp t
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM X x WHERE x.id = t.x_id) AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Y y WHERE y.id = t.y_id);
```

The above insert checks, for every row, that the specified `x_id` and `y_id` values in fact have matching primary keys in the two parent tables.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried with "INSERT INTO IGNORE..." due to a comment below my question and it seem to work. Your solution will work fine so thank you, i will use your answer for something else ! :)

Comment: @Zayders Yes, and I also answered originally with `INSERT IGNORE`.  This and my answer do different things, but if `IGNORE` works for you, then go with it.

Comment: @Zayders : the INSERT IGNORE will insert all row and you will have "dead" data in your database since you have some deleted foreign key. You should delete them (try a left join with other table that return null)